# Quart python : send websocket broadcast message from curl and display it

Tags: python, websocket, messaging, quart

i have edited this way:

my curl command is:

```
curl -d '{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:5000/telepath
```

i want to display this posted data on every clients.
i grabed what i can on documentation but it s not easy for me.

here is my script:

```
from quart import Quart, render_template, websocket
from functools import partial, wraps
from quart import request, redirect, url_for, copy_current_websocket_context
import asyncio

app = Quart(__name__)

connected_websockets = set()

def collect_websocket(func):
    @wraps(func)
    async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        global connected_websockets
        queue = asyncio.Queue()
        connected_websockets.add(queue)
        try:
            return await func(queue, *args, **kwargs)
        finally:
            connected_websockets.remove(queue)
    return wrapper

async def broadcast(message):
    for queue in connected_websockets:
        await queue.put(message)

@app.route('/')
async def index():
    return await render_template('index.html')


@app.websocket('/ws')
@collect_websocket
async def ws(queue):
    print("$ $ $",queue)
    while True:
        data = await websocket.receive()
        print("\n {}".format(data))
        await websocket.send(f"echo {data}")



@app.route('/telepath', methods=['POST'])
async def telepath():
    global connected_websockets    
    data = await request.get_json()
    for queue in connected_websockets:
        await queue.put(data["key1"])
    return "\n Request Processed.\n"



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000)
```

and the template:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My TEST</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="message">
    <button>Send</button>
    <ul></ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var ws = new WebSocket('ws://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/ws');
      ws.onmessage = function (event) {
        var messages_dom = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
        var message_dom = document.createElement('li');
        var content_dom = document.createTextNode('Received: ' + event.data);
        message_dom.appendChild(content_dom);
        messages_dom.appendChild(message_dom);
      };

      var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
      button.onclick = function() {
        var content = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
        ws.send(content);
      };


    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var es = new EventSource('/telepath');
    es.onmessage = function (event) {
        var messages_dom = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
        var message_dom = document.createElement('li');
        var content_dom = document.createTextNode('Received: ' + event.data);
        message_dom.appendChild(content_dom);
        messages_dom.appendChild(message_dom);
      };

    
    });


    let socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:5000/ws");

    socket.onmessage = function(event) {
        alert(`Data received: ${event.data}`);
        
    };

    
    
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My final goal would be authentication, and to target who
can receive private message from the server.

**Impossible to transmitt the posted data via curl on mozilla or chrome client.**

Answer (score 3):

In your `collect_websocket` decorator you pass a `queue` argument to the websocket handler (`return await func(queue, *args, **kwargs)`) whereas your websocket handler accepts no arguments (`async def ws()`). This results in the error you see.

It looks like your `ws_v2` websocket handler is setup to work with the `collect_websocket` decorator (`async def ws_v2(queue)`), so I think you can just switch to using that and rewrite the telepath as so,

```
@app.route('/telepath', methods=['POST'])
async def telepath():
    global connected_websockets    
    data = await request.get_json()
    for queue in connected_websockets:
        await queue.put(data["key1"])
return {}
```

Note you don't need to create any queues in the `/telepath` route as this is done by your `collect_websocket` decorator and also as you need a queue per websocket connection. You also don't need to await the `ws_v2` handler, it will instead be called whenever there is a new websocket connection.

For the authentication I recommend you start with [Quart-Auth](https://gitlab.com/pgjones/quart-auth) (I am the author of the library).

---

Edit: Full code as requested,

```
import asyncio
from functools import partial, wraps

from quart import (
    copy_current_websocket_context, Quart, render_template, 
    request, websocket
)

app = Quart(__name__)

connected_websockets = set()

def collect_websocket(func):
    @wraps(func)
    async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        global connected_websockets
        queue = asyncio.Queue()
        connected_websockets.add(queue)
        try:
            return await func(queue, *args, **kwargs)
        finally:
            connected_websockets.remove(queue)
    return wrapper

async def broadcast(message):
    global connected_websockets 
    for queue in connected_websockets:
        await queue.put(message)

@app.route('/')
async def index():
    return await render_template('index.html')

@app.websocket('/ws')
@collect_websocket
async def ws(queue):
    await websocket.accept()
    while True:
        data = await queue.get()
        await websocket.send_json(data)

@app.route('/telepath', methods=['POST'])
async def telepath():   
    data = await request.get_json()
    await broadcast(data)
    return {}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000)
```

and the template,

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My TEST</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul></ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var ws = new WebSocket('ws://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/ws');
      ws.onmessage = function (event) {
        const messagesDOM = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
        const messageDOM = document.createElement('li');
        const message = JSON.parse(event.data).message;
        const contentDOM = document.createTextNode('Received: ' + message);
        messageDOM.appendChild(contentDOM);
        messagesDOM.appendChild(messageDOM);
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Which then works with curl,

```
curl -H "content-type: application/json" -d '{"message": "Hello"}' localhost:5000/telepath
```

Note that the server will send all the JSON data it receives to the client, but the client only uses the `message` key.

Comment: could you give full detailed working example please, i offer 100 points bounty ;-)

Comment: Yep, I've just added the full detailed working example. It allows you to post to the /telepath route that is then sent to the connected clients.